# Using XCode and CodeBlocks on the same C++ SDL2 project

Tags: c++, xcode, sdl, codeblocks, sdl-2

I've just received a MacBook Pro for cross-platform game development. I've been making an SDL2 game project on CodeBlocks for Windows and Linux, and everything's fine on both operating systems so far. However, when it comes to Mac OS X, it seems I've got to use XCode instead.

I could figure out how to create a working SDL project in XCode. However, I would like to create an XCode project that shares the same source code as my CodeBlocks project, which happens to be on a Git repository. I've yet to find out how to do that. However, I've already put the #ifdef platform preprocessor instructions in my source code.

Could you give me some tips for doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Use [CMake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMake) to generate platform-specific makefiles/IDE projects.

Comment: I'll be trying this thing. Thanks!